# Minimal generator of an algebra or a sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I may be asking a trivial question, but I am a bit confused about it. I have tried to search for the concept of a **minimal generator** of an algebra or a sigma-algebra on a set, but have found this concept nowhere. Suppose that I define a minimal generator of an algebra or a sigma algebra A, as a generator of A, none of whose proper subsets generate A. My question is: **Does every algebra or sigma algebra on a set have a minimal generator?** Also, if the answer is in the affirmitive, then is the proof constructive, or existential?

Comment: This sounds like asking for a minimal generating set for the abelian group of the rational numbers under addition: any two elements a and b belong to a cyclic subgroup.

Comment: The Borel sets on a Polish space has a minimal generating set: Without loss of generality, we can simply take the Cantor cube and the collection of all half cubes $\sigma$-freely generates the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets.

Answer (score 6):

Minimal generators of $\sigma$-algebras are treated in

> Bhaskara-Rao, K. P. S., & Rao, B. V. (1981). Borel spaces. PWN.

Among other things, it is shown there that every countably generated $\sigma$-algebra has a minimal generator. The problem is posed whether every $\sigma$-algebra has a minimal generator. This question received a negative answer in

> Aniszczyk, B., & Frankiewicz, R. (1984). [On minimal generators of
>   σ-fields](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm124/fm12417.pdf). *Fundamenta Mathematicae*, 124(2), 131-134.